# Suppressing messages in Rmarkdown using sink()

Tags: r-markdown

I am writing a Rmarkdown document about a package called SparseTSCGM and have trouble suppressing messages generated by functions in this package. The messages I'm referring to can be generated by the following code:

```
if(!require(SparseTSCGM)) install.packages('SparseTSCGM')
library(SparseTSCGM)
datas <- sim.data(model="ar1", time=10,n.obs=10, n.var=5, prob0=0.35,
              network="random")
res.tscgm <- sparse.tscgm(data=datas$data, lam1=NULL, lam2=NULL,nlambda=NULL, model="ar1", penalty="scad",optimality="bic_mod", control=list(maxit.out = 5, maxit.in = 5))
```

I have tried using the functions `invisible()` and `suppressMessages()` but these do not help in either Rmarkdown or the R console. I also tried adding the option `message = FALSE` as follows:

````
```{r message=FALSE}
library(SparseTSCGM)
datas <- sim.data(model="ar1", time=10, n.obs=10, n.var=7, prob0=0.35, network="random")
res.tscgm <- sparse.tscgm(data = data.fit, lam1 = NULL, lam2 = NULL, nlambda = NULL, model = "ar1", penalty = "lasso", optimality = "bic", control = list(maxit.out = 10, maxit.in = 100))
```
````

but this does not help.

I have found that I can suppress output in the R console using `sink('NUL')` (I'm working on a Windows system), but this approach does not work in Rmarkdown. When I try this approach the message I tried to suppress is still there but the Rmarkdown console gives a warning: `"Warning message: In sink() : no sink to remove"`.

Does `sink()` not work with Rmarkdown, is there another way do to this? If there is no solution I can always manually remove the section from the HTML file but that's a last resort.

Comment: I had the same issue. For me the only thing that worked is `results='hide'`  in the chunk options and create a new chunck to actually print out the results (usinkg `knitr::kable` or create a graph.).